# Login failed for user in windows service

Tags: c#, .net, service

Wrote one Windows Service in C# and install it through installutil. Now when i am trying to Start the service it says
 `"Service cannot be started. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'Domain\MachineName$'.at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlIn...`

Although, the app working fine as per it's functionality while testing but not sure the error giving.

Please help.

Comment: it seems you service can't able to create a connection check your connection string in app.config file

Comment: username/password mismatch or server name is incorrect. open your database and check if you're using (local)/(.SQLExpress) or any instances and specify it in connection string datasource

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create any SQL instance at ServiceBase.OnStart event? 
If so then you need to check the connection string that you are passing through, either through app.config (on installed folder path it would be your windowservicename.config) or via code.

In this connection string you are authenticating through windows login. Thus, you need to ensure that the window service that you are running under (you can check at window service property- security, which user it is assigned). This user must have an access to your SQL database.

Have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the instance name you mentioned in the connection string.

Open your sql server, login using Windows Authentication\SQL Authentication which you're using in your service. check the provided user name and password works for 'Domain\MachineName$' server.

You're making a db connection on your OnStart event, which fails to start the service due to  incorrect instance name or username/password combination.

and one more point to remember, make sure your service starts after sql starts when you reboot the machine. so that you wont get any login error on system rebooting. set your service as "Automatic - (Delayed)".